# Vim RegEx question: how to detect headings of markdown(.md) i.e. lines composed of '-' or '='

Tags: regular-expression, filetype-markdown

I'm learning Vimscript in [Learn Vimscript the Hard way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/16.html) and trying an exercise. Here is this:

> The lines "underlined" with = characters are treated as headings by Markdown.

`:onoremap ih :<c-u>execute "normal! ?^==\\+$\r:nohlsearch\rkvg_"<cr>`

> By this, Vim will delete the heading of whatever section you're in and put you in insert mode ("change inside heading").
>
> Markdown can also have headings delimited with lines of - characters. Adjust the regex in these mappings to work for either type of heading.

So I changed the regex(`?^==\\+$`) to this:

`?^\(==\|--\)\\+$`

Then replaced it. However, this regex can't find neither '-' headings nor '=' them.

What is the correct regex I want in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original regex is

```
?^==\\+$
```

which means, searching backwards (`?`) for start-of-line (`^`), followed by `=`, followed by another `=` which can be repeated several times (`\+` qualifier, followed by end-of-line (`$`).

The backslash needs to be doubled, because the regex is embedded into a double-quoted string, read [:h expr-quote](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-quote) why this is needed).

If you want to allow either `-` or `=` to find the headers, you would change the regex to be somthing like this:

```
 ^[=-]\+$
```

which comes down to, search start of line (`^`), any of the chars `-` or `=` at least once (`\+`) and end of line (`$`).

Note, that this would also find e.g. lines consisting of: `=-=-=-` If you would like to prevent this, you would need to capture the first character and make sure it comes several times:

```
^\([=-]\)\1\+$
```

Note: remember to double the backslashes, if you put this into a double quoted string.